# How to create a table using insert so columns are nullable?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, create-table

Using SQL Server 2008.

Here is a simplified example of my problem:

```
WITH    cte ( a )
          AS ( SELECT   1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   NULL
             )
SELECT * INTO a_tmp FROM cte

SELECT * FROM a_tmp
```

This creates the table called `a_tmp` with a nullable int column.

The next snippet, however creates the table with a non-nullable column:

```
WITH    cte ( a )
        AS ( SELECT   1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT   2
            )
SELECT * INTO a_tmp FROM cte
```

How can I change the second snippet to force the table to be created with all its columns nullable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it into a computed expression as generally these get treated as `NULL`-able unless wrapped in `ISNULL()`

```
WITH    cte ( a )
        AS ( SELECT   CAST(1 AS INT)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT   2
            )
SELECT * INTO a_tmp FROM cte
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to explicitly define a field as nullable in a table, the **right** way is to use `CREATE TABLE`.

As a workaround you can explicitly cast all your fields as their data types, but to me that seems like MORE work than just

`CREATE TABLE MyTable (id INT NULL, Otherfield varchar(100)...)`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `SELECT ... INTO`, any expression that uses a built-in function (e.g. CAST) is considered as NULL-able by the engine.

So if you use `CAST(somecol as int)` then the expression is NULLable.